# Homology of A Compact Manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I am working on a compact manifold $M$ of dimension $m$.

Moreover, I suppose that $M$ is oriented of fundamental class $ [M] \in H_m (M)$.

I want to show that I have an isomorphism  $H_\ast (M, \mathbb{Q}) \cong H_\ast (M) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.

I figured I'd use the poincaré duality which tells me that $ H^i (M) \cong H_{m-i} (M)$ via the map $ - \cap [M]$ ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: The comment of Carsten Schulz is short, but efficient: the universal coefficients gives you an exact sequence with the two groups you need, and something with the Tor functor. In the case where your coefficient group is a field, the Tor functor always gives 0. Take any book on the subject (Hatcher, Bredon) for precisions.